# Retrieve certain columns from Smartsheet api as csv?

Tags: smartsheet-api

Is it possible to use the Smartsheet api to retrive only certain columns from a sheet as a csv? The [get sheet](https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/#operation/getSheet) method is supposed to accept `columnIds` as a parameter, but I can't get it to work. Maybe this is because I am choosing csv as the acceptable response type and the option is not supported there? I am using cURL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Get Sheet as Excel/PDF/CSV](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?shell#get-sheet-as-excel-pdf-csv) operation doesn't support all of the same parameters that the regular [Get Sheet](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?shell#get-sheet) operation does. (See the docs I've linked to for details about supported parameters.) Therefore, the scenario you've described (getting only certain columns of data when retrieving the sheet in CSV format) isn't supported, since the [Get Sheet as Excel/PDF/CSV](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?shell#get-sheet-as-excel-pdf-csv) operation doesn't support the `columnIds` parameter.

As a not-very-efficient work around, you could achieve the outcome you're after by using several API requests:

1. Call the [Copy Sheet](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?shell#copy-sheet) operation to create a copy of the sheet.
2. Call the [Delete Column](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?shell#delete-column) operation once for each column you want to remove from the new copy of the sheet.
3. Call the [Get Sheet as CSV](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?shell#get-sheet-as-excel-pdf-csv) operation to retrive the new copy of the sheet (where you've just removed the columns you don't want).
4. Call the [Delete Sheet](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?shell#delete-sheet) operation to delete the new copy of the sheet, now that you've retrieved it.

Certainly not very efficient, but this should get you the outcome you're after. Perhaps worth considering if this is a one-time thing you're doing.